# Checking if linear code exists

Tags: coding-theory

At first I wanted to say Hello, because its my first post in this stack exchange!

I've just started my course in coding and cryptography and don't know if my approach is correct after reading the theory. The task was to check if a linear code (22, 13, 11) exists.

Below are my approaches. Would be very thankful for checking if my thinking is correct:

1. Simple check - minimum distance of linear code $ d \leq n-k+1 $.
   As I thought it's to trivial I checked next with the Hamming Bound
2. Hamming Bound.

First I've calculated $ t = 5 $ and $ C $ from the formula $ C \leq \frac{2^n}{\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + ...+\binom{n}{t} }  $ and the result was  $ C \leq 119$ but the code is linear so $ C \leq 118 $.  But $k =13 $ so such code does not exist ?

1. Last  check was with Gilbert–Varshamov bound stating that a linear code exists iff $ \binom{n-1}{0}+...+\binom{n-1}{d-2} \leq 2^{n-k}  $ which showed it is not a valid code.

Are those approaches correct? Are there any other methods to check if a linear code exists?

Comment: Hamming bound works (your item 2. looks good: $k=13\implies |C|=2^{13}=8192$). Not surprisingly Singleton bound does not. Griesmer bound works. This code is so larger and has such a high minimum distance that everything other than Singleton bound succeeds in proving its non-existence

Comment: And welcome to Math.SE :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank You! So I assume my solutions are correct :-) Is there like 'limit' when to use the singleton bound? It showed a false inequality meaning that the code does not exist? And are there more methods to prove the code existance? And in what situation should i use the proper one (can I use the Hamming Bound and Griesmer anytime i want)?

Comment: The Gilbert-Varshamov bound cannot be used to show that a code does not exist. The bound asserts only that codes whose parameters satisfy certain conditions exist; it does not deny the existence of codes whose parameters do not satisfy the conditions.

Comment: @DilipSarwate so the Hamming Bound approach is correct to prove the existence?

Comment: No, the Hamming bound is used to prove non-existence. No code with parameters $(n,C,d)$ can exist if the total volume of the $C$ spheres of Hamming radius $(d-1)/2$ exceeds $2^n$. In your calculation, that no $(22,C,11)$ code _can_ exist if $C \geq 119$, and so a $(22,8192,11)$ code cannot exist. Note also that the Hamming bound _does not prove existence._ There may, or there may not, exist a $(22,118,11)$ code but the Hamming bound has nothing to say either way about it.

Comment: @DilipSarwate so my answer is correct:P It showed that given code doesn't exist, because the inequality isn't fulfilled. Otherwise please propose a different solution, because I'm a bit lost now! Thanks for the answer

Comment: Yes, your answer based on the Hamming code is correct (with the minor change that linearity of the code tells you that $|C|\leq 64$, not just $118$), and Jyrki already told you that your answer is correct in the very first comment on your question. I began commenting only on your use of the GV bound.